# Add a bone at each vertex location?

Tags: armature, bones

So I was wondering if it was possible to somehow get the location of every vertex in a not-so-complex mesh (76 vertices) and add bones to that locations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Manual Selection and Creation

1. Select mesh object, go into edit mode. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Select vertex.
3. Snap cursor to vertex. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, *C**u**rsor to Selected*
4. Go into object mode and select the armature object.
5. Go into edit mode and create a bone (at the cursor's position). <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
6. Repeat for all vertices.

#### Use a python script

I created a script for you, which does what you intend.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def AddBonesAtVertices(length, use_normals):
    objects = bpy.context.view_layer.objects
    obj = objects.active
    if not obj or obj.type != 'MESH':
        return

    points = []
    normals = []
    data = []
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        p = obj.matrix_world @ v.co
        target = v.normal @ obj.matrix_world
        dir = target - p
        dir.normalize()
        dir = dir * length
        n = p + dir * (-1)
        points.append(p)
        if not use_normals:
            n = Vector((p[0], p[1], p[2] + length))
        normals.append(n)
        data.append([p, n])

    amt = bpy.data.armatures.new(obj.name + "_vBones")
    rig = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + '_vRig', amt)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rig)
    objects.active = rig

    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    for i, l in enumerate(zip(points, normals)):        
        bone = amt.edit_bones.new(str(i))
        bone.head = l[0]
        bone.tail = l[1]
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()



bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
AddBonesAtVertices(0.5, False)
```

Paste the script into the text editor, selected the mesh object and run the script.

[image]

Comment: Could you update this script for Blender 2.82? I'd need it :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Wow! Works like magic! :D (I spent an hour failing to fix the script) - Thank you a lot!

Comment: I must admit, I have not yet learned the 2.8 api properly. I hope this doesn't break when your are on the wrong "viewlayer" or "collection".

Comment: But it sure does the job :) This is what I'm trying to achieve in whole: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/168241/8282

Comment: Regarding the manual method, you can choose the size of each bone you add (without having to scale the bone, which sometimes offsets/deforms it in undesirable ways) by adding the bone in object mode and then command-J joining it with the main armature.