# Setup bones on cloth sim so that you can transfer it to Unity via FBX export

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, parent

So, I would like to have this happen with a script for each vertice of an object:

[image]

I just couldn't to make it work :/ Except only some parts of it (scripts found from everywhere).

## Building blocks:

#### Add an empty to each vertex:

```py
    import bpy

vertices = [i.co for i in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices if i.select]
vertices

for vert in vertices:
    print(vert)
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', location=vert)
```

#### Add a bone to each vertex ([thanks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68918/8282)):

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def AddBonesAtVertices(length, use_normals):
    objects = bpy.context.view_layer.objects
    obj = objects.active
    if not obj or obj.type != 'MESH':
        return

    points = []
    normals = []
    data = []
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        p = obj.matrix_world @ v.co
        target = v.normal @ obj.matrix_world
        dir = target - p
        dir.normalize()
        dir = dir * length
        n = p + dir * (-1)
        points.append(p)
        if not use_normals:
            n = Vector((p[0], p[1], p[2] + length))
        normals.append(n)
        data.append([p, n])

    amt = bpy.data.armatures.new(obj.name + "_vBones")
    rig = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + '_vRig', amt)

    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rig)
    objects.active = rig

    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    for i, l in enumerate(zip(points, normals)):        
        bone = amt.edit_bones.new(str(i))
        bone.head = l[0]
        bone.tail = l[1]
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()



bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
AddBonesAtVertices(0.5, False)
```

#### The command for vertex parenting (I think)

```py
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='VERTEX')
```

---

## Yay!

Thanks for the answer below :) I managed to make a flag cloth sim and bake it to the bones and transfer that to Unity via FBX nicely.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags when tagging a question. Also which part of the script fails? Is it the making of the empties, the adding of the bones, the vertex parenting? When you narrow down which exact part isn't working you may be able to simplify the title.

Comment: Thanks :) I managed to tidy the title a bit. Pretty much all aspects of the process fails, I can only produce parts of it (the provided scripts), I don't know how to combine them, I'm just a beginner. Thanks for cleaning up the tags :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without edit bones.**

[image]

Edit bones can be a little tricky, in script below instead have added the default single bone object, copied it to match number of verts, joined and constrained to the empties.

IMO this is a little easier to use for something like this and avoids dicking around with edit mode and heads and tails.

- Select a mesh object in object mode. Run Script.
- Adds an empty vertex-parented to each vertex.
- Empties added to a collection and linked to scene.
- Add a single bone armature using the operator.
- Make a copy, select and link to scene for each other vertex.
- Join to original.
- For each pose bone, constrain to each empty.
- Make the constrained pose the rest pose. (*Else all bones are Y up at origin*)

Test script.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

mtcol = bpy.data.collections.new("Empties")
scene.collection.children.link(mtcol)

for v in me.vertices:
    mt = bpy.data.objects.new(f"Vert {v.index}", None)
    mtcol.objects.link(mt)
    mt.parent = ob
    mt.parent_type = 'VERTEX'
    mt.parent_vertices = [v.index] * 3

# add an armature
bpy.ops.object.armature_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
for i in range(len(me.vertices) - 1):
    ob = context.object.copy()
    ob.data = ob.data.copy()
    scene.collection.objects.link(ob)
    ob.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.join()
arm = context.object

for pb, mt in zip(arm.pose.bones, mtcol.objects):
    con = pb.constraints.new('COPY_LOCATION')
    con.target = mt


# set constrained pose as rest.
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
bpy.ops.pose.armature_apply()
```

[Can a punishment be implemented for using the word "vertice" in a Q/A?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.0331)

Comment: Seems to be acceptable https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertice ... but again you've made the point on these (two) questions.

Comment: Bring that one up on any opportunity... the seriousness of the answers, to a question that was surely tongue in cheek,  is IMO priceless.

Comment: Definitely, I have to take English lessons ... I don't understand anything that is idiomatic ... or idiomatices, I don't know.

Comment: or idiotic mates.  Another common spelling mistake lately is loose (rhymes with goose), for lose (news)

Comment: Woow, such an elegant script! Thank you so much :D (sorry can't help to not make this comment)

Comment: It works so well :) But, could one step be automated as well? I mean applying the first pose to be the rest pose. 

You see, I need to do that in order to be able to bind another mesh to the bones with automatic weights. (In order to bring a cloth sim to Unity as FBX with baked bone animations)

But it's okay if it can't be done - I just always need to remember to do that after using the script :) Thank you already so much! Cheers!

Comment: @ManuJärvinen done, see edit. Flag looks great.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm :) Thank you so much!

About the flag, thank you! :) if I moved the forces the flag could be even nicer.