# Generate Rig from vertecies

Tags: python, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, geometry

I am looking for a way to automate this setup:

[image]

Basically, i want to generate a armature with bones for every vertex of a selected mesh. Ideally, the bones should point in the vertex's normal direction (although that's not that important, they can also just point up or forward).

Because my mesh has overlapping vertices, it's important that the weight painting happens automatically. Each vertex should **only** get assigned to it's designated bone, which doesn't work with blender built-in auto weight's system. (See comment's for more details)

Does anyone here happen to have a python script laying around that does this? Or maybe know about an add-on for this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68907/add-a-bone-at-each-vertex-location ?

Comment: @Lutzi thanks, but this doesn't assign any weights. I'm working with a somewhat high poly mesh that has overlapping vertecies so that part is pretty important. Automatic weight's wont work with that and painting them by hand would be a nightmare

Comment: Why don't automatic weights work? Do Automatic Weights and then > Clean Weights (0 | keep single)

Comment: @Leander Automatic weights assigns 0.5 to overlapping vertecies, assigning both vertecies to both bones. The clean weights function doesn't seem to do anything in my case

Comment: Your question didnt say anything of overlapping vertices and only shows manifold topo (cube) as an example. Could you update it and include this info please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Automatic Weights

1. Create the bones using [this script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68907/add-a-bone-at-each-vertex-location).
2. Parent with automatic weights.
   [image: result]
   (It works with the Suzanne model.)
3. Use Weight Paint > Weight > Limit Total > 1 to limit the amount of weight groups per vertex.
   [image: weight groups]

#### Create the weights with a script

```
import bpy
import math

ob = bpy.context.object

# optionally remove existing modifiers and vertex groups
for mod in ob.modifiers:
    ob.modifiers.remove(mod)
for v in ob.vertex_groups:
    ob.vertex_groups.remove(v)

# store positions for base and tail of bones
coords = [[ob.matrix_world @ v.co, ob.matrix_world @ (v.co + v.normal)]
    for v in ob.data.vertices]

# the padding will be used to create unique names
# eg: 002
padding = math.ceil(math.log10(len(coords)))

# create the armature and link it to the scene
rig_data = bpy.data.armatures.new("rig_data")
rig = bpy.data.objects.new("rig", rig_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rig)

# add the armature modifier
mod = ob.modifiers.new(type='ARMATURE', name="rig")
mod.object = rig

# go into edit mode (to add bones)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rig
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# add a bone for each coordinate pair
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
    # create a unique name
    name = str(i).zfill(padding)
    
    # add new bone
    bone = rig_data.edit_bones.new(name)
    bone.head, bone.tail = coord[0], coord[1]
    
    # assign weight to new group
    grp = ob.vertex_groups.new(name=name)
    grp.add([i], 1, 'REPLACE')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```